# Problems with importing some modules (here numpy) (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath')

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

i would like to use opencv and tried to install the needed modules.
i need to install everything manually per donwload and then pip or install.

I am using Python 3.10.1 and Pip 21.2.4.

My project is an an venv.

The Following Modules are installed:

- altgraph==0.17.2
- cmake @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/cmake-3.22.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
- cycler @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
- Cython @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Cython-3.0.0a9-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- fonttools @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/fonttools-4.29.0-py3-none-any.whl
- future==0.18.2
- kiwisolver @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- matplotlib @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/matplotlib-3.5.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- numpy @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- opencv-python @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/opencv_python-4.5.5-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- packaging==21.3
- paho-mqtt==1.6.1
- pefile==2021.9.3
- Pillow @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/Pillow-9.0.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
- pyinstaller==5.0.dev0
- pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.5
- pyparsing==3.0.7
- python-dateutil @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
- scikit-build==0.12.0
- six @ file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

i use a minimal script to check the import :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\User\\Python\\modules\\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl')
sys.path.append('c:\\users\\User\\python\\pyproj\\project1\\lib\\site-packages')

#import matplotlib
import numpy as np
```

that is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj\project1\import.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl\numpy\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\User\Python\modules\numpy-1.22.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "C:\Users\User\Python\pyver\python3101\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

i am new in python and i cant find the problem.

Greetings
Chorum

Addition:
with

```
import os
print("PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
print("PATH:", os.environ.get('PATH'))
```

i get:

```
PYTHONPATH: None
PATH: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\imc\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\imc\shared;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\SYSTEM\TNG
```

python is working fine. i used following modules before:

- sys
- tkinter
- ctypes
- time

Comment: I forgot the Hello! but i cant edit it in... so here: Hello !

Comment: FYI You can edit the post :) Do you have Python 3.10?

Comment: yeap 3.10. I tried the edit button, wrote the Hello! but it wasnt saved :( i am a friendly fellow !

Comment: Then you should go https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html here and try to read what official docs are saying.

Comment: "i need to install everything manually per donwload and then pip or install." that's wrong, you only need to `pip3 install opencv-python` and then pip will download that from PyPI, as well as resolve dependencies and download those too. no manual downloads anywhere.

Comment: if i am behind a proxy with whitelist i can not download via pip. thats why my information about my installation method.
i wonder: do i append a path with sys.path.append ... ? i dont find the appended path in the list with `os.environ.get`

Comment: i commented out the sys.path.append's and put the paths in pythonpath. now i only have the error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: problem solved with adding the paths. now i have a problem with with pyparsing...

Comment: I think this post can be closed... i am going module per module and adding the paths. module for module is working .... thx for the help!

Comment: Pip allows you to use a proxy server.  I strongly suspect setting that up rather than manually setting paths will be easier in the long run.